# An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to perform a "soft delete". I.e. insert a new entry when matched and when not matched just insert an entry.

For example:

```
MERGE TargetTable AS targetT 
USING SourceTable AS sourceT ON sourceT.Npi = targetT.Npi
WHEN MATCHED AND IsNull(targetT.SPI, '') <> '' THEN
    UPDATE SET targetT.Isdelete = 1 --Update Only One Column
    --And also insert a new row
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    --Perform insert operation
```

Comment: WHEN MATCHED means the record already exists, so an insert doesn't really make sense. Update does...

Answer (score 0):

The merge statement will not work this way.  You would have to do it the old fashioned way (using a stored procedure would work).

It looks like you are trying to create an archive record.  If this is true I suggest you use the merge as it is intended to be used and use an after update trigger to do your auditing needs.